# Automatically accept License Agreements for 3rd party software?

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

I am running a Windows Server 2008 R2 server in our company. We create a log of accounts for our users which only use the server for a few days.

We ae facing the issue that each new user has to accept lots of license agreements for all the 3rd party software, e.g. Adobe PDF reader etc. when they start the first time.

Is it possible to get around all these "accept" screens and dialogues? I am thinking that we could eventually present a list of license agreements to the user before we actually create th account and have him signed it. So he has agreed them any way.

I am looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Adobe offers a free product named [Adobe Customization Wizard](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4950) which allows you to remove the EULA, update notifications, etc. You may also enforce these options via registry edits. Unfortunately, this sort of option will be vendor/product specific for other titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify @Jason Berg's answer - many vendor packages have an internal / LAN specific deployment package that strips out the junk your average 3rd party installer includes. This usually includes tool bars, EULAs etc. The IS department effectively agrees to the EULAs on the behalf of the client in order to download the deployment package.

Searching for redistribution or deployment packages plus your third party application names should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If all users are logging onto a terminal server, you can create a user profile where you accept all of the license agreements already, then make that user profile your default profile. This may not work following a software upgrade or patch, so you should continue reading anyways.

If you're not using a terminal server, your best option is to install custom versions of software where the license agreements are already accepted. Adobe offers a customization wizard to do that and lots of other software manufacturers provide the same type of ability during installation.